# Basic derivation of reward calculation

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The screenshot below shows definition given in the Sutton and Barto book on page 49. Could someone please give a nudge in the direction of why the conditional expectation of reward is calculated this way? In particular how the ratio of probabilities on the right is arrived at? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, here's the derivation for the statement in question.
[image]